# very strange strpos() behaviour

Tags: php, strpos

I can't find an explanation for this.

I am looking to see if a certain CSS definition exists within a CSS file.

The haystack is `$css` and the needle is `'tbs_wwrapper'`

My haystack DOES contain `'tbs_wrapper'` (with one 'w') but does NOT contain `'tbs_wwrapper'` (with two 'w') and yet my search function returns `true` as if there was a match.

How is this possible?

Here is my function:

```
function tbs_quick_css_find($definition) {
global $css;
if ( strpos(PostFriendlyCSS_ENcode($css), $definition) !== false )
    return true; // match found
else
    echo '<span class="error">The definition "'.PostFriendlyCSS_DEcode($definition).'" was not found in the CSS file</span>';
}
```

Comment: Why are you using !== instead of !=? "!==" isnt for objects like "===".

Comment: @sensorario: http://www.php.net/strpos Also how is either of those operators specific to objects?

Comment: Look at the very first comment on the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @sensorario, OP is doing right i guess.. From PHP docs , `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`

Comment: $a!==$b means not identical: it returns TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type. False is boolean and it is not of the same type of strpos() return values 'cause them are integers.

Comment: Isnt right: we are not working with objects. So, ... we are not working with types. What happens with (strpos()!=-1) ?

Comment: @sensorario: Strings, Booleans, numbers - these are all types as well, even though they're not objects. And `strpos()` *never* returns -1 so that comparison would always return true.

Comment: What does `PostFriendlyCSS_ENcode()` do? Maybe that's causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, but we are interested in check if something is true or false. We are not interested in types.

Comment: @sensorario: No. `strpos()` doesn't just return true or false. Please read the documentation that's been linked to more than once above - it explains exactly why to use !==.

Comment: @sensorario If you check strpos of a string and it is in the first (0th) position, and you use `!=FALSE` then you are going to get FALSE when you need TRUE

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've paid more attention to documentation. Sorry guys. So, ... the issue maybe is inside PostFriendlyCSS_ENcode($css) as @tecbrat says.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you guys... PostFriendlyCSS_ENcode() is just a function I wrote which replaces a few special characters with others... it doesn't do anything to letters-only variables such as 'tbs_wwrapper'... should I be using a different function to check whether the needle is contained in the haystack?

Comment: So we need to see what is the result of `PostFriendlyCSS_Encode`

Comment: this is that function:

    function PostFriendlyCSS_ENcode($definition) {
 $definition = str_replace('#','III_pound_III_',$definition);
 $definition = str_replace('.','III_dot_III_',$definition);
 $definition = str_replace(',','III_comma_III_',$definition);
 return $definition; 
}

as upi cam see it doesn't do anything that should make a match of tbs_wrapper be the same as tbs_wwrapper

Comment: Please, update your question.

Comment: In your `else` block, add `echo PostFriendlyCSS_Encode($css)."\n\n".$definition;` and make sure they BOTH are correct.